# Does killing someone cancel their Contingency?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-death, triggered-actions

I was looking at the [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) spell, and besides being a very versatile spell, I noticed a couple things about it that really stand out:

- It does not have a method to cancel it other than removing the
  material (a 1500GP ivory statue) from my person. (Besides [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) or casting *contingency* a second time)
- It has a 10-day duration.
- It does not require a reaction (or ANY kind of action) for the spell charged into it.
- Automatically makes ME the target of the charged spell, regardless of who it can normally target.

With this information, could I be DEAD for several days and have my power activate after a trigger, such as "9.5 days from casting this spell, trigger if I am dead"? Or does killing the caster prevent the contingent spell from triggering?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Contingency doesn't end when the caster dies.

Nothing in the [spell description for *contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) indicates that it ends if the caster dies, as long as the duration isn't up and they still have the material component on their person. A DM might argue that a corpse can't have anything "on their person", but that seems overly picky to me.

Nor do the [general rules for spell duration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spellcasting#Duration) state that all spells end when the caster dies.

[*Dispel Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) cast on the caster (or their body) would end a *contingency* early. Other than that, a wizard can certainly arrange to have a 1-action spell of 5th level or less cast on their body up to ten days after they die.

(Note, for any wizards who have multiclassed into cleric, that *raise dead* takes an hour to cast, so is off the table).

Comment: A very relevant question brought up Revivify as an option, but only if you've been dead for 1 minute.  A few things you COULD do after several days would be to write a message, set off a bomb, or teleport your corpse 500 feet away.

Comment: What if their body is chewed up, burned, digested, or otherwise destroyed and there's no person left for the object to be on?

Comment: @jpmc26 That is among the many, many, many nuances present in the interpretation of all spells (and, indeed, all D&D rules) that are adjudicated by the DM.